# Finding the sum of digits in a list if they meet a certain criteria // TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
what = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
len(what) # size 16
rwhat = what[::-1]    # reverse the order of what & work with this
rwhat

checkDig = rwhat[0] # the leftmost [originally rightmost] digit which is the # checkDigit is 6
checkDig # 6
withCheck = [] # to append later when we add all single digits

everySec = rwhat[1:16:2] # we don't want to double the checkDigit. extract value of every second digit.
everySec # [5, 3, 1, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]

def double(num):
    return [j * 2 for j in everySec] # double the value of every second digit
xx = double(everySec)
xx # [10, 6, 2, 18, 14, 10, 6, 2]

def getSingle(y): # we want to sum the digits of numbers (that were doubled) that are greater than 9 and keep these sums along with the numbers that didn't need to be summed.
    u = 0
    while y:
        u += y % 10
        y //= 10
    return u
```

When I try 
`getSingle(xx)` to return the latest function and get a list of only single digits, I'm given this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'`

I've explained what's going on in the comments throughout the code, but if more clarification is needed please feel free to ask. This isn't even the entire program, but I need this last function to work to move forward.

EDIT
Ok, so it works. Now if I wanted to create a function outside of all this code (as in this code will be in the inside of the new function), how would I go about doing so when the function should have only 1 parameter which is a multidimensional array w/ 16 columns. I'm stuck on how/where I'd indicate this specification.

Comment: You can see that `xx` is an array.  Saying `while [non-empty array]` is going to return True but you need to extract the values from the array before doing math with them

Comment: The error is exactly right.

`xx` is of a list type, which contains (from your comment) `[10, 6, 2, 18, ...]`.

Comment: Why has `def double(num)` a parameter `num` (which is not used)-  you still operate on the global `everySec` inside of `double(num) ?(+1 for a well formed question and code)

Comment: does that mean I need to change it from an array into something else?

Comment: Yes, you need to iterate through each item in the list `xx`.
You basically do the same thing in `def double(num)`

Comment: (1) You have a *list*, not an *array*.  (2) As others have already pointed out, you cannot do math on the list as a whole.  You have to deal with the individual numbers.

Comment: You can use map to execute a function on every elements of the list. For instance `yy = map(getSingle, xx)`, will execute getSingle on every element of xx.

Comment: @atru, so I just tried map and I'm getting `<map at 0x1f1f30106d8>` ?

Comment: Sorry! Still on Python 2.7 :) In Python 3.X you should use `list(map(...))`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I thought the parameter was just a filler name

Comment: @atru oooh it works! thank you!!

Comment: @zainy Then create some other list of numbers and put it to double(...) ;o) I bet youll get not your new (different) lists of doubles out

Comment: Glad to help! :) Cosider @PatrickArtner comment, you'll regret the current version ;)

Comment: That are errors that *bite* - code works, no error, then you use it somewhere else and never will know what goes wrong

Comment: for your followup question, which should really just be a new question, you should take your function definitions ('double` and `getSingle`) outside of this new function. the numpy solution I gave would work on your n-dimensional array

Comment: forgot to mention, if you went with the numpy solution, you need to change `double` to just be array*2 and adjust the function you're using for reverse to be something that makes sense. I'm not sure why you reverse in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the fact that when you call `getSingle(xx)`, you are inputting a list instead of an integer. The `%` can not be cast to the whole list in the way you intended. Possible solutions include:

**Iterate over List**

```
def getSingle(y):
    y = eval(repr(y)) #deep copy y in case we want to use it again later
    u = [0]*len(y)
    for i in range(len(y)):
        while y[i]:
            u[i] += y[i] % 10
            y[i] //= 10
    return u
```

This would apply your digit summing operation to all of the elements of the list and return the sum in u.

**Numpy**

Alternatively, if you plan on doing operations on the whole list many times, we could use `numpy` (never import a library to use only once)

```
import numpy as np
def getSingle(y):
    y = np.array(y)
    u = np.zeros(y.shape) #create an array of 0s the same size
    while np.any(y): #checks to see if any elements in y are more than 0
        u += y % 10 #operation applies to all in y
        y //= 10    # operation applies to all in y
    return u
```

**Map**

And as pointed out in the comments, another alternative would be to use `map` on the existing function.

```
result = map(xx, getSingle) #fixed code
```

You would have to call this outside of the function definition in place of the original call

```
result = getSingle(xx) #original code with error
```

documentation for map is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

In python 3 map returns an object which can be turned into a list by applying the list function

```
result = list(map(xx, getSingle))
```